# How could I get the position (line, column) of attribute from NSXMLParser?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macos, nsxmlparser

I need to do some mark up on my UI with XML file. How could I get the line number and column number of specific attribute from NSXMLParser?

For example, I want mark up `minimumInteritemSpacing="10"` from the code snippet below, so I need the line and column number.

```
<collectionViewFlowLayout key="collectionViewLayout" minimumLineSpacing="10" minimumInteritemSpacing="10" id="Rhn-xg-EmY">
    <size key="itemSize" width="50" height="50"/>
    <size key="headerReferenceSize" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>
    <size key="footerReferenceSize" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>
    <inset key="sectionInset" minX="0.0" minY="0.0" maxX="0.0" maxY="0.0"/>
</collectionViewFlowLayout>
```

The methods in `XMLParserDelegate` never trigger for `attributes`, and none of them was designed for that. That's why I ask solution for it, maybe not using `NSXMLParser`.

I know it's super easy to get the attributes, but there is no position information. And answers in other questions don't care about the position.